# Smarter File nesting inside csproj wildcard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, blazor, csproj

I need better file nesting.

I have Index.razor, Index.razor.cs, Index.Model.cs, Index.Interface.cs inside the Pages folder.

In csproj

I have

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Update="Pages\Index.razor.cs" DependentUpon="Pages\Index.razor" />
   <Compile Update="Pages\Index.Model.cs" DependentUpon="Pages\Index.razor" />
   <Compile Update="Pages\Index.Interface.cs" DependentUpon="Pages\Index.razor" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I created this functionality into Wildcard

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Update="**\*.Interface.cs" DependentUpon="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Interface', '.razor'))" />
   <Compile Update="**\*.Model.cs" DependentUpon="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Model', '.razor'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What I want is better version of this

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Update="**\*.Interface.cs" Condition="Exists('Check Razor')" >
      <DependentUpon>"$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Interface', '.razor'))"</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Update="**\*.Model.cs" Condition="Exists('Check Razor')" >
      <DependentUpon>"$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Model', '.razor'))"</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>

   <Compile Update="**\*.Interface.cs" Condition="Exists('Check cshtml')" >
      <DependentUpon>"$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Interface', '.cshtml'))"</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   <Compile Update="**\*.Model.cs" Condition="Exists('Check cshtml')" >
      <DependentUpon>"$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Model', '.cshtml'))"</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>

   Need to check here also
   <Compile Update="**\*.Interface.cs" DependentUpon="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Interface', '.cs'))" />
   <Compile Update="**\*.Model.cs" DependentUpon="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileName)').Replace('.Model', '.cs'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So that I can use Isolation in cshtml and razor project without hasle.

Comment: Has your function been implemented? If not, can you tell me what you mean by the "isolation" you want to achieve through wildcards?

Comment: Isolation means files nesting. For example, Index.razor.cs is under Index.razor file. I have Index.Model.cs, Index.Interface.cs files. These files need to nest under Index,razor file. This setup is done. I need next version like, these function need to work in razor, cshtml, xaml you got my point?

Answer (score 0):

For example to work in xaml, you can use MSBuild15's static update syntax.

```
<Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
```

MSbuild splits paths into ( => ) and ( => ), so it can be used to reference xaml files.

Filenamefoo.xaml.csfoo.xamlExtensionfoo.xaml.cs.cs%(Filename)

Comment: I hate file names too long like Foo.Model.xaml.cs, foo.Extensions.xaml.cs

Comment: Are you looking for a more concise approach?